# Which functional interface to use if method don't accept anything but return object of the class in java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, functional-interface

I have one existing Java 7 method which accepts nothing but return class instance. I want to change it in java 8 using any existing functional interface but don't know what i can use here.

public NotificationPage infraSelection() {
......
return this;
}

Here NotificationPage is class name.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking or why the version of java matters

Comment: I want to ask if their is any functional interface available which don't accept anything in argument but return object of class so that I can use method chaining.

Comment: You should probably add an example or something to your question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the `Supplier<T>` interface?

It declares the method `T get()`.